# Create dummy variables in one table based on range of dates in another table

Tags: r, data.table

I have two tables.  `table1` looks like this

```
  date       hour     data
2010-05-01     3        5
2010-05-02     7        7
2010-05-02     10       8
2010-07-03     18       3
2011-12-09     22       1
2012-05-01     3        0
```

This is stored as a `data.table` with key set on `date` and `hour`.
I have another table, that looks like this.  It's my `outages` table.

```
 resource        date_out                date_back
   joey       2010-04-30 4:00:00      2010-05-02 8:30:00
   billy      2009-04-20 7:00:00      2009-02-02 5:30:00
   bob        2011-11-15 12:20:00     2010-12-09 23:00:00
   joey       2012-04-28 1:00:00      2012-05-02 17:00:00
```

I want to add columns to `table1` where those columns are the resource from the `outages` table.  I want the values in those columns to be 0 for whenever there isn't an outage and 1 for when there is.

The result for this example should be.

```
  date       hour     data     joey      billy      bob
2010-05-01     3        5       1          0         0        
2010-05-02     7        7       1          0         0 
2010-05-02     10       8       0          0         0 
2010-07-03     18       3       0          0         0 
2011-12-09     22       1       0          0         1
2012-05-01     3        0       1          0         0
```

In actuality my `table1` has about 2500 rows and my `outages` table has 19000.  The only way I could think to do this is to loop through each row of the `outages` table and then insert 1s into `table1` in the correct places.  My code relies on `table1` being in order so at least it doesn't have to scan 100% of that table for every row of `outages`.  However the below takes over 4 hours for my data.

```
for (out in 1:length(outages$resource)) {
  a<-as.character(outages[out]$resource)
  #if column doesn't exist then create it
  if (a %in% colnames(table1)==FALSE) {
    table1$new<-0
    setnames(table1, "new", a)
    }
  midpoint<-round(length(table1$date)/2,0)
  if (table1$date[midpoint]+table1$hour[midpoint]*60*60>=outages[out]$due_out && table1$date[midpoint]+table1$hour[midpoint]*60*60<=outages    [out]$due_back)
  {
    while(table1$date[midpoint]+table1$hour[midpoint]*60*60>=outages[out]$due_out && midpoint>=1 && midpoint<=length(table1$date)) {
      table1[midpoint,a:=1,with=FALSE]
      midpoint<-midpoint-1
    }
    midpoint<-round(length(table1$date)/2,0)
    while(table1$date[midpoint]+table1$hour[midpoint]*60*60<=outages[out]$due_back && midpoint>=1 && midpoint<=length(table1$date)) {
      table1[midpoint,a:=1,with=FALSE]
      midpoint<-midpoint+1
    }
  } else {
    if (table1$date[midpoint]+table1$hour[midpoint]*60*60>outages[out]$due_back) {
      while(table1$date[midpoint]+table1$hour[midpoint]*60*60>outages[out]$due_back && midpoint>=1 && midpoint<=length(table1$date)) {
        midpoint<-midpoint-1
      }
      while(table1$date[midpoint]+table1$hour[midpoint]*60*60>=outages[out]$due_out && midpoint>=1 && midpoint<=length(table1$date)) {
        table1[midpoint,a:=1,with=FALSE]
        midpoint<-midpoint-1
      }
    } 
    midpoint<-round(length(table1$date)/2,0)
    if (table1$date[midpoint]+table1$hour[midpoint]*60*60<outages[out]$due_out) {
      while(table1$date[midpoint]+table1$hour[midpoint]*60*60<outages[out]$due_out && midpoint>=1 && midpoint<=length(table1$date)) {
        midpoint<-midpoint+1
      }
      while(table1$date[midpoint]+table1$hour[midpoint]*60*60<=outages[out]$due_back && midpoint>=1 && midpoint<=length(table1$date)) {
        table1[midpoint,a:=1,with=FALSE]
        midpoint<-midpoint+1
 }
 }
 }
if (sum(table1[,a,with=FALSE])==0) {
  table1[,a:=NULL,with=FALSE]
}
}
```

To quote everybody's favorite infomercial line "There's got to be a better way".

Comment: Could you post the `str` output for your data, so we can see the data types? Or better yet, the `dput` output?

Comment: Maybe something like `table1[,is_out:=any(outages$date_out <time & time < outages$date_back)]`? This depends on your first making a `table1$time` variable that combines the two columns you have now.

Comment: please provide `dput` output. It's hard to copy/paste columns with spaces (the ones between yyyy-mm-dd and hh:mm:ss).

Comment: eddi's answer below works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way of achieving what you want. This assumes your `table1`'s time precision is 1 hour. Though it can be modified to an arbitrary precision, it will perform much better for larger time intervals as it constructs the full sequence of possible times in the `date_out`-`date_back` range. Note, I used slightly different tables from OP to illustrate overlapping intervals and to correct some mistakes in OP.

```
table1 = data.table(date = c("2010-05-01", "2010-05-02", "2010-05-02", "2010-07-03", "2011-12-09", "2012-05-01"), hour = c(3,7,10,18,22,3), data = c(5,7,8,3,1,0))
outages = data.table(resource = c("joey", "bob", "billy", "bob", "joey"), date_out = c("2010-04-30 4:00:00", "2010-04-30 4:00:00", "2009-04-20 7:00:00", "2011-11-15 12:20:00", "2012-04-28 1:00:00"), date_back=c("2010-05-02 8:30:00", "2010-05-02 8:30:00", "2009-06-02 5:30:00", "2011-12-09 23:00:00", "2012-05-02 17:00:00"))

# round up date_out and round down date_back
# and create a sequence in-between spaced by 1 hour
outages[, list(datetime = seq(as.POSIXct(round(as.POSIXct(date_out) + 30*60-1, "hours")),
                              as.POSIXct(round(as.POSIXct(date_back) - 30*60, "hours")),
                              60*60)),
          by = list(resource, date_out)] -> outages.expanded
setkey(outages.expanded, datetime)

# merge with the original table, then run "table" to get the frequencies/occurences
# and cbind back with the original table
cbind(table1, unclass(table(
                outages.expanded[table1[, list(datetime=as.POSIXct(paste0(date, " ", hour, ":00:00")))],
                                 resource])))

#         date hour data bob joey
#1: 2010-05-01    3    5   1    1
#2: 2010-05-02    7    7   1    1
#3: 2010-05-02   10    8   0    0
#4: 2010-07-03   18    3   0    0
#5: 2011-12-09   22    1   1    0
#6: 2012-05-01    3    0   0    1
```

Comment: Ok this looks like it will meet my needs perfectly.  I successfully reproduced this with just the made up data.  However when I try to do this with my real data I get an error with the line that produces outages.expanded.  The error is Error in seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(round(as.POSIXct(date_out) + 30 * 60 - 1,  : 
  'to' must be of length 1  I'm not sure what I should be looking for to fix this.  Any pointers on that error?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor you have duplicate (`resource`,`date_out`) pairs. You can either remove the duplicates, or if you want to keep them, do the 'by' by row names instead `by=row.names(outages)`

Comment: @DeanMacGregor after some thought - you'd need to modify it a bit to get it to work with row names, I recommend getting rid of duplicates instead, as they shouldn't be there anyway from your data description

Comment: the modification mentioned above is to add `resource` to the list in `outages`: `outages[, list(resource=resource,datetime=seq...), by = row.names(outages)]`

Comment: I just did `setkey(table1, resource, date_out)` `table1<-unique(table1)` which fixed that.  Now that I've got your method instead of mine I can do this in less than 1 minute instead of hours so that's is awesome...Thanks.

Comment: Hi. This is better done with `roll=TRUE`, iiuc. Set a key on outages$date_out. roll join from table1 to it. Keep the join results where the table1.date < outages.date_back, too, and done. It should be sub 1 second for this on this size. For further examples of roll joins try searching for '[data.table] "roll"'.

Comment: +1 @MatthewDowle - I was too lazy to replace this answer, but here's a very similar question where I used the `roll` argument instead of the above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649885/replacing-nested-loop-in-r/16652700#16652700