# Replacing nested loop in R

Tags: r, nested-loops, apply

I am very new to R and searched about this on forums but couldn't get a close enough solution for this. I am trying to do a mapping between the ip address & corresponding geo locations. I have 2 data sets.

```
Set-a (1,60,000 rows):
ip(int) | ID(int)

Set-b (16,00,000 rows):
Ip1(int) | Ip2(int) | Code(str) | Country(str) | Area1(str) | Area2(str)
```

I am trying to do the following:
**if ip lies between Ip1 & Ip2 then add Country & Region to Set-a.**

I am doing the following (obviously not a very good way to do this):

```
ip1<-as.numeric(b$Ip1)
ip2<-as.numeric(b$Ip2)
country<-b$Country
area1<-b$Area1
area2<-b$Area2

for(i in 1:160000){
  for(j in 1:1674303){
    if(a[i]>ip1[j] & a[i]<ip2[j]) {
                                   a$country[i]<-country[j]
                                   a$area1[i]<-area1[j]
                                   a$area2[i]<-area2[j]}
   }
}
```

Can someone please tell me an efficient way to do this. This is taking a lot of time. (for i=1 to 100 took some 10 mins to run).

**The sample data set-b is:**

```
Ip1, Ip2, Code, Country, Area1, Area2
"0","16777215","-","-","-","-"
"16777216","16777471","AU","AUSTRALIA","QUEENSLAND","SOUTH BRISBANE"
"16777472","16778239","CN","CHINA","FUJIAN","FUZHOU"
"16778240","16778495","AU","AUSTRALIA","VICTORIA","MELBOURNE"
"16778496","16778751","AU","AUSTRALIA","NEW SOUTH WALES","SYDNEY"
```

It is in continuos increasing order.

The dput(head(a)) & dput(head(b)) respectively are:
(refer sample data above)

```
structure(IP_Addr = c("38825563", "38921619", "42470287", "42471923","42473368","42473428"), 
 Desc_value = c("0", "1.2", "4.97", "1", "5.9", "22.06")), .Names = c("IP_Addr", "Desc_value"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

structure(list(Ip1 = c("0", "16777216", "16777472", "16778240", 
"16778496", "16778752"), Ip2 = c("16777215", "16777471", "16778239", 
"16778495", "16778751", "16779263"), Code = c("-", "AU", "CN", 
"AU", "AU", "AU"), Country = c("-", "AUSTRALIA", "CHINA", "AUSTRALIA", 
"AUSTRALIA", "AUSTRALIA"), Area1 = c("-", "QUEENSLAND", "FUJIAN", 
"VICTORIA", "NEW SOUTH WALES", "-"), Area2 = c("-", "SOUTH BRISBANE", 
"FUZHOU", "MELBOURNE", "SYDNEY", "-")), .Names = c("Ip1", "Ip2", 
"Code", "Country", "Area1", "Area2"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Maybe you could provide a small example data set?

Comment: This will be easier if the `Ip1` and `Ip2` ranges are different for every country/region in `Set-b`, so can you tell us if that's the case?  And even if not, I bet if you first sort your sets so the IP values are in order, it'll lead to a simpler "screening" algorithm.

Comment: @Frank, Carl : 
Yes, the ranges are different & continuos increasing order.

Sample data set is

Ip1, Ip2, Code, Country, Area1, Area2
"16777216","16777471","AU","AUSTRALIA","QUEENSLAND","SOUTH BRISBANE"
"16777472","16778239","CN","CHINA","FUJIAN","FUZHOU"
"16778240","16778495","AU","AUSTRALIA","VICTORIA","MELBOURNE"

Comment: Please, a sample data set _that we can read in_. :) Also, it would be better to edit your question to add the information. I forgot to mention: you can use `dput(a)` and `dput(b)`...

Comment: @Carl, Frank, I am sorry for this. The formatting gets screwed here. I have added the sample data set in the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As you can see, we're very confused about the state of your data. Please create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). As Frank mentioned, pasting the output of `dput(head(a))` and `dput(head(b))` would be very useful.

Comment: Updated the dput(head(a/b)) in the questions. Also included sample data set-b, if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a `data.table` solution:

```
# Let's take Blue Magister's example set:
set.seed(10)
a <- data.frame(ip=sample(16777216:16778751,10,replace=TRUE))
b <- read.table(sep=",",header=TRUE,text='Ip1, Ip2, Code, Country, Area1, Area2
"0","16777215","-","-","-","-"
"16777216","16777471","AU","AUSTRALIA","QUEENSLAND","SOUTH BRISBANE"
"16777472","16778239","CN","CHINA","FUJIAN","FUZHOU"
"16778240","16778495","AU","AUSTRALIA","VICTORIA","MELBOURNE"
"16778496","16778751","AU","AUSTRALIA","NEW SOUTH WALES","SYDNEY"')

b$Ip1 <-as.numeric(b$Ip1)

# include library, convert to data.table
library(data.table)

a = data.table(a)
b = data.table(b, key = "Ip1")

# and now the actual computation
a = b[a, roll = Inf][, Ip2 := NULL] # yep, amazingly, it's *that* simple in data.table
setnames(a, "Ip1", "ip")            # you can also include, exclude whatever columns you want
a
#          ip Code   Country      Area1          Area2
# 1: 16777995   CN     CHINA     FUJIAN         FUZHOU
# 2: 16777687   CN     CHINA     FUJIAN         FUZHOU
# 3: 16777871   CN     CHINA     FUJIAN         FUZHOU
# 4: 16778280   AU AUSTRALIA   VICTORIA      MELBOURNE
# 5: 16777346   AU AUSTRALIA QUEENSLAND SOUTH BRISBANE
# 6: 16777562   CN     CHINA     FUJIAN         FUZHOU
# 7: 16777637   CN     CHINA     FUJIAN         FUZHOU
# 8: 16777634   CN     CHINA     FUJIAN         FUZHOU
# 9: 16778161   CN     CHINA     FUJIAN         FUZHOU
#10: 16777875   CN     CHINA     FUJIAN         FUZHOU
```

Had `Ip1` been an exhaustive list of numbers that `ip` could match, then above would simply be a merge (of `Ip1` in `b` with first column of `a`, i.e. `ip`), but `data.table` also provides an option of what to do when there is no exact match. You can tell it to e.g. roll the previous observation forward (which is what I did above), or roll it back or roll to the nearest observation - see `?data.table` for a little more information.

Comment: Wow...Thanks a tonne. This does not take even 2 secs :) . I tried searching but still not very clear on how this is working.

Comment: @GauravNemade I added a short explanation, hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't you remove the 2nd loop using,

```
j = intersect(which(ip1 < x[i]), which(ip2 > x[i]))
if  (length(j)==1){
         a$country[i]<-country[j]
         a$area1[i]<-area1[j]
         a$area2[i]<-area2[j]
}else{
         cat("Multiple matches found!\n")  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Didn't know about intersect & which. 
This makes the process faster but it is still taking a long time (around 120 iterations/min - 22 hours for entire process). Is there some a faster way than this?

Comment: @GauravNemade - was `data.table` of `findInterval` faster? "Accept" the answer that worked best for you.

Answer (score 3):

I would try `findInterval`:

```
#create example
set.seed(10)
a <- data.frame(ip=sample(16777216:16778751,10,replace=TRUE))
b <- read.table(sep=",",header=TRUE,text='Ip1, Ip2, Code, Country, Area1, Area2
"0","16777215","-","-","-","-"
"16777216","16777471","AU","AUSTRALIA","QUEENSLAND","SOUTH BRISBANE"
"16777472","16778239","CN","CHINA","FUJIAN","FUZHOU"
"16778240","16778495","AU","AUSTRALIA","VICTORIA","MELBOURNE"
"16778496","16778751","AU","AUSTRALIA","NEW SOUTH WALES","SYDNEY"')

b$Ip1 <-as.numeric(b$Ip1)
indices <- findInterval(a$ip,b$Ip1,rightmost.closed=FALSE,all.inside=FALSE)
a <- data.frame(a,b[indices,c("Country","Area1","Area2")])
```